# ESP32 usb and external power supply

Tags: esp32

I'm trying to build my own ESP32 board with an external 3.3v power supply.
I have FT23x1 uart IC with handshake.

1. Is it ok if I power the esp32 with the external power supply and still connect the +5V from usb to uart (same ground tho). Right now, what I have is +3.3V from the external connected to uart and everything but the code uploading doesn't seem to work (maybe my handshake is the problem).
2. When I disconnect the usb and using the external power supply, do I have to bring pin EN of the ESP HIGH to make it work? (And pin GPIO0?).

Comment: 1. Yes it is ok. 2. Esp32 download uses software handshake. The control lines are used to reset and control the boot mode of the esp32.

Comment: The esp32 datasheet tells you what you need to do with EN and gpio0